# Excel - Adding serial number to list of sorted address data to rank individual first names in non-sequential manner

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Good afternoon,
I have a list of 70,000 first name, last name and address. The list has been sorted by Address, City, State and Zip. Which means that family members that lives at the same address will be listed next to one another.
I need to add a number to an empty cell whenever there is a duplicate last name but unique first name under the same household address - meaning Jim Johnson will have a 1 and Teresa Johnson will have a 2 in the empty cell. But if 10 rows down there is another family with the last name Johnson, the serial number will start at 1, not at 3.

For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEUZG.png)

I have tried using: =COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2) but the problem is that when this formula is used it assigns the next sequential number that matches the last name so it no longer cares that the duplicates were listed under one address (so values would go beyond the 1, 2 and it would assign a 3 to a "Pina" family that has a different address.

I tried =IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0)) but this formula did the same.

Is there a simple way that I am missing to have a sequential number be added to the third column when the last name matches and the first name doesn't and that it doesn't take into account other matches not lumped together by address?

Comment: Is it possible to have the same first *and* last name at the same address. i.e. could Jim Johnson be listed twice at the same address? If yes, how should it be handled?

Answer (score 0):

You need more than the single condition `COUNTIF` will give you:

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B8,B8,C$2:C8,C8)
```

Should do the job, but will include duplicates in the count.

If you want duplicates to not add to the count, you need something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A8,"<>"&A8,B$2:B8,B8,C$2:C8,C8)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand how column A is used within your sample data and formulas. The *Last Name* seems to be column B.

```
=IF(B1<>B2, 1, COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:2)/(B$1:B2<>B2), 1)), B2))
```

[image]

That formula could actually be reduced to,

```
=COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:2)/(B$1:B2<>B2), 1)), B2)
```

The wrapping IF should reduce calculation overall but its impact depends on how many groups are within your data set.

Answer (score -1):

## Simple IF

In cell `C2`:

```
=IF(B1<>B2,1,C1+1))
```

If you have empty cells add another `IF`:

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(B1<>B2,1,C1+1))
```

This will cover your image.

But what if the next family at the next address has the same last name as the previous one? Then you will have to bring the Address into the fold i.e. add another condition.

Let's say that the Address is in column `G`:

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(B1<>B2,1,IF(G1<>G2,1,C1+1)))
```

This will cover the Address.

But what if the next family lives at the same Address but in another City and has the same last name as the previous one? ... etc.

You could even go further, but it's up to you to determine when to put a stop at this 'paranoia'.